# How to foce min-width on empty div

Tags: css, layout, html, grid

I'm trying to display some 'aligned' text -- and I've decided to use a 6 column layout, except it isn't really a column layout because each row can have a cell (like in tables) span multiple columns. However, I'm doing this using   only.

My CSS looks like below, and it works as long as there is content. However, it fails if there is no content. Please help!

.p_row { 
            width: 900px; 
            padding-top: 0px;
            clear: left; 
        }

```
    .p_col1 { min-width: 140px; }
    .p_col2 { min-width: 280px; }
    .p_col3 { min-width: 420px; }
    .p_col4 { min-width: 560px; }
    .p_col5 { min-width: 700px; }
    .p_col6 { min-width: 840px; }


    .labeldesc {
        display: inline-block; 
        float: left;
        text-align: left; 
        vertical-align: top; 
        margin-right: 0px; 
    }

    .field {
        display: inline;  
        float: left;
        text-align: left; 
        vertical-align: top; 
        margin-right: 0px; 
    }
```

Sample data:

```
<div class="Row Container">
    <div class="p_row">
        <div class="p_col1 labeldesc">Condition:</div>
        <div class="p_col1 field">@clinicalCondition.Description</div>
        <div class="p_col1 labeldesc">Is Chronic:</div>
        <div class="p_col1 field">@clinicalCondition.ChronicIndicatorString</div>
        <div class="p_col1 labeldesc">Date</div>
        <div class="p_col1 field">@clinicalCondition.DateString</div>
    </div>

    <div class="p_row">
        <div class="p_col1 labeldesc">Comment:</div>
        <div class="p_col5 field">@clinicalCondition.Comments</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above, I want all the labels/fields to align, but if one of the field values is string.empty, then the min-width does not work. If I remove the float: left, it also doesn't work. And the display: inline-block doesn't seem to do anything, nor does the min-width.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm using both FireFox and IE, and no luck.

Comment: If an element has zero width OR height, as well as no border/padding/etc, it won't take up space.

Comment: That is to say, try setting a min-height.

Answer (score 5):

To follow-up on Shmiddty's comments, I added a min-height: 1px; and it worked like a charm.